# Compiler Incooperation in frozen binary creation

Tags: python, binary

Why is it important to transform the interpreter into binary to in a frozen binary out of an python program? Isn't it the whole point of binary that it doesn't need to be interpreted.

Comment: It's not compiling the Python to machine code. It's just packaging the Python byte code with the Python interpreter in an executable.

Comment: Writing a compiler that *just* reimplements the interpreter wouldn't be any faster than the existing interpreter, and writing a compiler that does *more* than that would likely be quite difficult (given that nobody seems to have ever bothered.)

Comment: I see so a frozen binary isn´t actually compiled down to machine code. why is it named frozen binary then?